# Error when running Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started learning rails and was faced with a problem. Anything that I write in rails console give me this:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `    ' for main:Object
from (irb):1
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-       4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/untitled7/bin/rails:4:in `require'
from C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/untitled7/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: what is the command you run?

Comment: rails generate controller welcome index, rails new blog, and so on.

Comment: you don't run those commands inside IRB - you run them from your terminal.

Comment: Please read Chris Pine's https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/